# support multiple instances of views in eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In eclipse 3.x, we can able to open multiple instances of view part by providing different secondary id. How can i achieve the same behaviour in eclipse 4, I am not able to find any property of part which support this behaviour.

Other question is I am migrating 3.x application to 4.x using compat layer, i have imported 3.x views in application model and added them in perspectives using placeholders. My problem is if i open first instance of same view, it opens at appropriate partsashcontainer as defined in application model but after that if i open another instance of view, it opens in any area of the perspective instead of defined layout?

So how can i force eclipse 4 to open a view in one layout area if i am opening multiple instances of the view simultaneously?

Comment: In pure e4 you use `EPartService.createPart` to create parts from a part descriptor and add them to the children of the required part stack. But if you are including the compatibility layer that may well cause confusion.

Comment: So is there a way to attach viewparts to partstack programatically in compatibility layer, i thought i will get partstack from model service and attach the part into stack but dependency injection is not working for me in compatibility layer. Is there any other way to get e4 partstack/ e4 part reference programatically? or more specifically get the model service instance? As i think with help of model service i will be able to get part stack/part instance.

Comment: I have tried to get the modelService from IEclipseContext but it is coming null always.
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EModelService=null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as suggested by @greg-449, I have to create part using EpartService and then attach the part to partstack. As i am using comapt layer so it is not straight forward and have to write some dirty code to achieve that:

```
                IEclipseContext serviceContext = E4Workbench
                        .getServiceContext();
                final IEclipseContext appContext = (IEclipseContext) serviceContext
                        .getActiveChild(); 

                EModelService modelService = appContext
                        .get(EModelService.class);
                MApplication app = serviceContext.get(MApplication.class);
                EPartService partService = serviceContext
                        .get(EPartService.class);
                MPartStack stack = (MPartStack) modelService.find(
                        "partstack.2", app);
                MPart part = modelService.createModelElement(MPart.class);
                part.setElementId("viewID");
                part.setContributionURI("bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView");
                part.setCloseable(true);
                part.getTags().add(EPartService.REMOVE_ON_HIDE_TAG);

                stack.getChildren().add(part); // Add part to stack
                MPart viewPart = partService.showPart(part,
                        PartState.ACTIVATE); // Show part
                ViewReference ref = ((WorkbenchPage) PlatformUI
                        .getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                        .getActivePage()).getViewReference(part);
                IViewPart viewRef = ref.getView(true);
```

Using this we can open the view using E4 and get the instance of IViewpart to perform other operations of 3.X